# code generation using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

In my scala source files

**File.scala**

```
@casejsTraitNative trait Variables extends js.Object {
val first: Int
}

case class Model(in:String)
```

I want to replace traits with `@casejsTraitNative` with some boiler plate  during compile time

Expected Result : **File.scala**

```
trait Variables extends js.Object {
val first: Int
}
object Variables {
@inline def apply(first: Int): Variables = {
val p = FunctionObjectNativeMacro()
p.asInstanceOf[Variables]
}
def copy( source: Variables, first: OptionalParam[Int] = OptDefault): Variables = {
val p = FunctionCopyObjectNativeMacro()
p.asInstanceOf[Variables]
}
}

case class Model(in:String)
```

I can create expected source string using `scalameta`,but i don't know which sbt task i need to hook to modify source files before they passed to compiler...

Comment: look up `sourceGenerators`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Seth Tisue, the way to fix this is by modifying the sbt source generators keys in your project http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html. You can there use Scalameta if you use sbt 1.x. Otherwise, you can't because Scalameta does not cross-compile to 2.10.x, the Scala version sbt 0.13.x uses.

Another way of solving this problem is annotation macros. Have a look at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html, but that's more complicated.

All in all, I think the best solution is to use Paiges (https://github.com/typelevel/paiges). It's a little bit more constrained that Scala Meta, but it should allow you to generate that code and more.